# What rivets should be used for gutter work?

Tags: gutters

I'm looking to buy pop rivets to do some gutter replacements, but the smallest "advertised for gutter work" pack available was a 100pk. I'd probably only need 20 at the most (short span). There weren't any dimensions listed, but common sense says they would only need to be around 1/8" x 1/4". Assuming any substitutes should also be aluminum.

What size would be adequate for joining aluminum gutters?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your gutter brand's seam overlap. A narrow riveting area should prompt a small rivet (1/8") because you do not want to drill a large hole (for a thicker rivet) which could weaken the gutter material in the riveted area, causing failure of the gutter material under stress.

The grip range required is determined by combined material thickness.

Answer (score 1):

I recently used 1/8" (3mm) wide, 1/8" (3mm) grip aluminum rivets for fastening aluminum gutter end caps on. Worked great.

I definitely wouldn't go much wider than 1/8" for fastening gutter end caps because there is only about 1/2" of aluminum to fasten to.

Comment: Gutter caps crimp on. And still have to be caulked.

Comment: @BillWeckel I've seen lots of professionals on youtube using special gutter end cap crimpers, but I didn't want to buy a $50 CAD tool that I would use only once. Or did you mean just crimping with regular pliers?

Comment: You can just use pliers too. Hell, I use a downspout crimper, but I've used whatever pliers I've had laying around too. Like i said, the end caps still have to be caulked, which will hold the end cap in place once it dries.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use self tapping sheet metal screws? You've gotta caulk the inside of the gutter at your seams and end caps anyway...

Comment: Screws protrude inside trapping debris and leads to clogged gutter down spouts. Screws are the Worst Fastener For Gutters!

Comment: Not so much protruding (rivets also protrude, but less). I had a customer who had a problem with screws rusting out and leaving nasty stains on her nice block paving. Took the screws out and put aluminum rivets instead.